# Может ли роутер 100 Мбит поддерживать свитчи гигабитные в локалке?

Tags: сеть

Я так понимаю, что через роутер в локалке трафик не идёт, следовательно при установке гигабитных свитчей скорость вырастет. Стоит ли это делать?

Comment: Стоит... если грамотно их подключить.

Comment: нарисуйте топологию сети http://soft-landia.ru/netcracker.html

Comment: Да нечего там рисовать! К роутеру одним-единственным кабелем подключен свитч, от которого всё и раздаётся!Но вообще-то я уже понял, что скорость внутреннего трафикапри такой конфигурации зависит именно от скорости свитча, а не роутера, который внутри только адреса раздаёт, и шлюзом наружу служит!

Comment: ну тогда принимай ответ чей нибудь

Answer (score 2):

Может ли роутер 100 Мбит поддерживать свитчи гигабитные в локалке? - вопрос некорректен по своей сути.
Обмен между устройствами будет происходить по-любому, но со скоростью более медленного устройства.
Т.е., предположим, свитчи внутренней локалки обеспечивают Гигабит (равно как и карты на компах), а выход вовне (т.е. то что обеспечивает рутер) - будет 100-мегабитный. Но ничего страшного - все будет работать.
По крайней мере - у меня работает :)

Comment: Не! Мне не нужно наружу, а только по внутренней локалке! Как я понимаю, роутер только IP через DHCP компам в локалке раздаёт, а собственно трафик идёт через свитчи. (У меня от роутера один кабель до свитча, а там уже - вся контора.) Вопрос в том, правильно ли я это понимаю? Если правильно, то скорость обмена в локалке при установке гигабитных свитчей должна вырасти на порядок, независимо от скорости роутера.

Comment: Да. При условии, что и на компах гигабитные карты - если этого нет, то нет и смысла ставить гигабитный свитч.  За исключением одного случая - когда надо связать между собой несколько свитчей. Тогда их подключаем между собой по гигабитным каналам.

Comment: Не забываем, при необходимости г-эзернета на компах, и патчкорды использовать категории 5е - иначе толку не будет ни от сетевушек, ни от свитчей гиговых...

Comment: Это я в курсе, просто у меня раньше либо сплошь сотка, либо гиг, а тут вот, вроде скомбинировать можно.

Answer (score 2):

Роутер больше чем надо через себя не пропустит, а то есть роутер будет работать на скорости до 100 МБит. Если во внутренней сети за роутером будет стоять коммутатор с пропускной способность в 1ГБит и все подключенные к нему машины будут иметь сетевой интерфейс с пропускной способностью в 1ГБит, то сетка внутри будет гигабитной.Но трафик который пропускает роутер, больше во внутрь и наружу будет не более 100 МБит.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какие цели у вас и какой трафик. Но в общем случае, стоит.

Comment: 1С, клиент-сервер, тонкий клиент.